# Showing $f(x,y)=\partial_x\partial_yF(x,y)=\partial_y\partial_xF(x,y)$

Tags: probability-theory

Consider $X,Y$, two random variables. Its joint cdf $F_{X,Y}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R^2$. I want to show rigorously that $$\frac{\partial^2 F_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\partial y \partial x}=\frac{\partial^2 F_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}= f( x, y)$$

My proof:
There exists the Radon-Nikodym derivative $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ such that
\begin{align*}
F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_{(-\infty,x]\times(-\infty,y]} f(\tilde x,\tilde y)d(\tilde x,\tilde y)
\end{align*}
By Fubini's theorem, we have that we can express this as iterated integrals
\begin{align}
F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^x\left[\int_{-\infty}^y f(\tilde x,\tilde y)d\tilde y\right]d\tilde x=\int_{-\infty}^y\left[\int_{-\infty}^x f(\tilde x,\tilde y)d\tilde x\right]d\tilde y
\end{align}
Now, since $x\mapsto F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and $y\mapsto F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ are strictly increasing, their derivatives exists a.e. (Theorem 3.23 in Folland). We denote these derivatives by 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\partial x}
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\partial y}
\end{align*}
respectively. Now, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Lebesgue Integrals, (Theorem 3.35 in Folland)
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\partial x}&=\int_{-\infty}^y f( x,\tilde y)d\tilde y\\
\frac{\partial F_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\partial y}&=\int_{-\infty}^x f( \tilde x, y)d\tilde x
\end{align*}
Now, if $f$ is continuous at $x,y$, then, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we get that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 F_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\partial y \partial x}&= f( x, y)\\
\frac{\partial^2 F_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}&=f(  x, y)
\end{align*}
So a key assumption is continuity of the density.